# Can a caster using Bigby's Interposing Hand still be attacked in melee?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, combat

Bigby's Interposing Hand doesn't fill its space. However, the hand does move between the caster and a target to provide them with half cover against that target, and the target can't move through the hand's space if its strength score is less or equal to the hand's strength score.

Can a creature faced with that spell still attack its caster in melee?

Comment: [A related question is here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/56877/22566)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes the creature can attack the caster.**

> **Bigby's Hand**: You create a Large hand of shimmering, translucent force in an unoccupied space that you can see within range... It has a Strength of 26 (+8) and a Dexterity  of 10 (+0). The hand doesn't fill its space. When you cast the spell and as a bonus action on your subsequent turns, you can move the hand up to 60 feet and then cause one of the following effects with it.
>
> **Interposing Hand:** The hand interposes itself between you and a
>   creature you choose until you give the hand a different command. The
>   hand moves to stay between you and the target, **providing you with half
>   cover against the target**. The target can't move through the hand's
>   space if its Strength score is less than or equal to the hand's
>   Strength score. If its Strength score is higher than the hand's
>   Strength score, the target can move toward you through the hand's
>   space, but that space is difficult terrain for the target.

The creature can attack the caster with a melee attack if the creature has more than 26 Strength therefore can move through the hand's space (difficult terrain for the creature) to get in 5ft (10 with a reach weapon) of the caster. The hand will still provide the half cover giving +2 bonus to caster's AC. If the attacker can attack from farther away however the hand can only grant the cover bonus. **The reach has to be greater than 10ft to avoid the hand as it's a Large hand and covers 10x10ft square**

If the caster would attack with a melee weapon however, the creature can't take advantage of the half cover as the hand specifies one way advantage (bold for emphasis on description).

Also any creature not targeted by the interposing hand will have no trouble getting close or attacking the caster.

Comment: A creature without 26 Strength could also still attack the caster by using a reach weapon and the Battlemaster maneuver *lunging attack* for temporary 15-foot reach. But again, the caster would still benefit from half cover.

Comment: The way I read the spell, the hand provides the cover, and the creature can't (for example) touch or grapple the caster.   I don't see in the text where the hand voids an attack (for example a ranged or reach attack) from being able to be made.  In other words, your title is correct, but your presenting the requirement for a 26 strength for an attack isn't clear in the spells' text.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast The requirement for 26 strength seems primarily to be for the purpose of getting in range. As mentioned in another comment, a creature with 15 foot reach could attack without entering the Hand's squares, but otherwise would need to move into them which requires 26+ strength.

Comment: @KamilDrakari I don't see that specificity in the text, I'll go and read through it again.  Thanks.  It may be that I am misunderstanding the point being made about "The hand doesn’t fill its space." I think a 10' reach weapon could attack, even though the target has half cover.  The only other uses of range for the hand are 5', so it seems to be in a 5'space between the caster and one other creature. Why would it take 15' to reach for an attack?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I will admit that my assumption of 15 foot reach only came from Speedkat's comment, which I might have also misinterpreted.

Comment: A melee attack can only be made from a short range (max 15 with Speedkat's example, lunging attack maneuver) and the hand stops your target from getting close unless your target has more than 26 strength. So a melee attack can't be made until those specific conditions are met.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast it's a **Large** hand so covers 10' that's why it takes 15' to avoid the hand.

Comment: @FenrirG Yet the text of the spell says that the hand does not occupy the space.  I think that is what has me puzzled. *The hand doesn't fill its space*

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I believe that means in any other situation you can move into the hand's 10x10 square. Interposing Hand specifies that your target can't unless they meet the strength requirement to do so.

Comment: @FenrirG For that one creature, it's no-go terrain.  For anyone else it doesn't fill the space.  Is that how it works?  "A creature you choose" is the key phrase ?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Yes, except when the target has more than 26 strength which negates the hand.